# response code always give 200

Tags: java, android, http-post, server-response

i'am tring to login into website with post method ... to right here the code is code but the response always give me 200 ... i want to know if i logged in successfully with the right username and password or not !!! ... also if i removed permitAll() it give me networkonmainthreadexception

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void sendPost()  {

     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://svuonline.org/isis/login.php?");

    String user=username.getText().toString();
    String pass=password.getText().toString();
    String fpage="/isis/index.php";

  /*  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }*/

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", user));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass", pass));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_otp", null));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from_page", fpage));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String Rcode=response.toString();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Rcode+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to print the response instead of the statusCode()

Comment: for one, don't leave empty catch blocks like that. secondly, your url appears to be `login.php`,  not `index.php`, according to the source of the page. finally, don't ever ever use `permitAll`.

Comment: ok guys i used your hints ... please check the edited Question text agine ...i'am new with android by the way !!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it here:

[HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

```
10.2.1 200 OK

The request has succeeded.
```